# C++ Raspberry Pi Controlling GPIO I/O via class/objects with Header file

Tags: c++, class, raspberry-pi, gpio

This question comes after this subject :

[Methods and parameters declaration problem in a class with header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60657246/methods-and-parameters-declaration-problem-in-a-class-with-header/60666556#60666556)

I tried to solve this next problem, but without success.

I'm using a raspberry pi with C++ and trying to implement a GPIO control through a class.

Therefore, I have :

- my main cpp file where I call the object (it works, I'm sure of that, you'll see) called "RobotControl03.cpp"
- the class cpp file called "Motorcontrol01.cpp"
- the header file called "Motorcontrol01.h"

My goal here is to simply call a "while(1)" loop where the states of the GPIO outputs is contently changing just for tests purpose. 
I check the output via my oscilloscope ;)

The problem is that it apparently execute correctly, shows what is expected on the screen (see screen capture at the bottom), but the output pins stay at 0V constantly.  :'(

I tried several modifications but nothing worked...

My code is more complex than what I show here, but I simplified it for tests purpose and it don't work anyway -_-

Main file called "RobotControl03.cpp" :

```cpp
#include <iostream> //for Cout to display stuff
#include <cstdio>
#include <csignal>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>   //for using vectors instead of arrays
#include <chrono>   //library for counting time
#include <thread>   //for multithreading
#include <termios.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>   //Raspberry pi GPIO Library
#include "RPMCounter01.h"
#include "MotorControl01.h" //looking in current dirrectory


bool RUNNING = true;    // global flag used to exit from the main loop

//###################################################################################
//  GPIO Pins definition
//###################################################################################
//int SPser = 13, SPclk = 19, SPrclk = 26; //Define the output pins used
int Motor0In = 17; //define the input pins used
int Motor1In = 18; //define the input pins used

/*int SPser = 13;
int SPclk = 19;
int SPrclk = 26; //Define the output pins used for the main shift registers
int PWMSPclk = 6;
int PWMSPrclk = 12; */

//###################################################################################
//    The array in which the different pins values will be stored
//###################################################################################
std::vector<std::vector<bool>> DataArr(16,std::vector<bool>(8, 0)); //create the array of data for the shift register. Each vector is of 8 values for the shift registers of the PWM control
//direction 0 = forward, 1 = backward. PWM = 0 is stop, over, it runs
 /* 0 = Direction   | Motor 1   8  = 
     * 1 = PWM      | Motor 1   9  = 
     * 2 = Direction    ] Motor2    10 = 
     * 3 = PWM      ] Motor2    11 = 
     * 4 =              12 = 
     * 5 =              13 = 
     * 6 =              14 = 
     * 7 =              15 = 
    */
int M0Speed = 0;
std::vector<bool> M0SpeedBin(8, 0); //Binary value of the motor speed 
int M1Speed = 0;    
std::vector<bool> M1SpeedBin(8, 0);

//###################################################################################
// Callback handler if CTRL-C signal is detected
//###################################################################################
void my_handler(int s) 
{
    std::cout << "Detected CTRL-C signal no. " << s << '\n';
    RUNNING = false;
}
//###################################################################################
//              MAIN
//###################################################################################
int main() 
{
    // Initialize wiringPi and allow the use of BCM pin numbering
    /*wiringPiSetupGpio();

    pinMode(SPser, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(SPclk, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(SPrclk, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(PWMSPclk, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(PWMSPrclk, OUTPUT);*/


    // Register a callback function to be called if the user presses CTRL-C
    std::signal(SIGINT, my_handler);

    MotorControl pouet; //Create an object, calling it pouet
    std::cout << "calling SendDataPWM " << '\n';
    pouet.SendDataPWM(DataArr); //calling the method of the object


}
```

The header file called "MotorControl01.cpp"

```cpp
//###################################################################################
// Class for creating the different shift register entry data
//###################################################################################

#include <iostream> //for Cout to display stuff
#include <chrono>   //library for counting time
#include <thread>   //for multithreading
#include <vector>
#include <wiringPi.h>   //Raspberry pi GPIO Library
#include "MotorControl01.h" //looking in current dirrectory

MotorControl::MotorControl(){   //constructeur
    //std::vector<std::vector<bool>> MCDataArr(16, std::vector<bool>(8, 0));    //the vector of vectors with boolean values in it for transmitting the motors control data
    //mFrequency = 0;
    //mGPIOOutputNb = 0;
    //###################################################################################
    //  GPIO Pins definition
    //###################################################################################
    SPser = 13;
    SPclk = 19;
    SPrclk = 26; //Define the output pins used for the main shift registers
    PWMSPclk = 6;
    PWMSPrclk = 12; // define the output pins to control the PWM shift registers
}

void MotorControl::SendDataPWM(std::vector<std::vector<bool>> MCDataArr){

    // Initialize wiringPi and allow the use of BCM pin numbering
    wiringPiSetupGpio();

    //initialize the pins
    pinMode(SPser, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(SPclk, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(SPrclk, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(PWMSPclk, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(PWMSPrclk, OUTPUT);

    // copy the data of the received vecor to preserve it
    //std::vector<std::vector<bool>> EditDataArr(16, std::vector<bool>(8, 0));
    //EditDataArr = DataArr;

while (1) {
    digitalWrite(PWMSPclk, HIGH);       //after looping through every value, ticking the register to load everything on the output of the main registers
    digitalWrite(PWMSPclk, LOW);
    std::cout << "PWM SP CLK"<<  PWMSPclk <<'\n';
    digitalWrite(PWMSPrclk, HIGH);      //after looping through every value, ticking the register to load everything on the output of the PWM registers
    digitalWrite(PWMSPrclk, LOW);
    std::cout << "PWM SP R CLK"<< PWMSPrclk <<'\n';
    digitalWrite(SPclk, HIGH);      //after looping through every value, ticking the register to load everything on the output of the main registers
    digitalWrite(SPclk, LOW);
    std::cout << "SP CLK"<< SPclk<<'\n';
    digitalWrite(SPrclk, HIGH);     //after looping through every value, ticking the register to load everything on the output of the PWM registers
    digitalWrite(SPrclk, LOW);
    std::cout << "SP R CLK"<< SPrclk<<'\n';
}
}
```

And the pretty header file that goes with it :

```cpp
#ifndef DEF_MotorControl
#define DEF_MotorControl
#include <vector>
class MotorControl{
    public:
        MotorControl();     //Constructeur
        void SendDataPWM(std::vector<std::vector<bool>> MCDataArr);

    private:
        //std::vector<std::vector<bool>> MCDataArr;
        int mFrequency;
        int mGPIOOutputNb;
        int SPser;
        int SPclk;
        int SPrclk; //Define the output pins used for the main shift registers
        int PWMSPclk;
        int PWMSPrclk;
};

#endif
```

Here is the command prompt result :

[image: Command prompt result]

I hope I don't need to show a picture of an oscilloscope showing nothing ;)

Edit :

For those thinking that setting the GPIO port "on" then directly "off" don't let it time to get at level, I've been doing that since the beginning, here is the kind of result expected :

[image]

I have been able to perfectly control a shift register with it. It's just since I've put my code in separate files that it don't work anymore :(

Thanks for your help !

EDIT 2 :

I've added some sleeps in the code :

```cpp
    digitalWrite(PWMSPclk, HIGH);       
    sleep(1);
    digitalWrite(PWMSPclk, LOW);
    sleep(1);
    std::cout << "PWM SP CLK"<<  PWMSPclk <<'\n';
}   
    digitalWrite(PWMSPrclk, HIGH);  
    sleep(1);
    digitalWrite(PWMSPrclk, LOW);
    sleep(1);
    std::cout << "PWM SP R CLK"<< PWMSPrclk <<'\n';

    digitalWrite(SPclk, HIGH);      
    sleep(1);
    digitalWrite(SPclk, LOW);
    sleep(1);
    std::cout << "SP CLK"<< SPclk<<'\n';

    digitalWrite(SPrclk, HIGH); 
    sleep(1);
    digitalWrite(SPrclk, LOW);
    sleep(1);
    std::cout << "SP R CLK"<< SPrclk<<'\n';
```

I looped through only one of the signals, it gives something like this :

```cpp
while (1) {

    //using namespace std::chrono;
    //CDelTime = 1ns; // interval at which a pin is turned HIGH/LOW

    digitalWrite(PWMSPclk, HIGH);       //after looping through every value, ticking the register to load everything on the output of the main registers
    //sleep(1);
    digitalWrite(PWMSPclk, LOW);
    //sleep(1);
    std::cout << "PWM SP CLK"<<  PWMSPclk <<'\n';
}
```

[image]

from where does this 6-7µs delay comes from?

Comment: My mistake - on earlier comments I thought this was an arduino. I'm only halfway through my first cup of coffee. However, it still looks like you're just setting a GPIO high then immediately setting it low. That shouldn't give the output enough time to slew high before it gets set low again.

Comment: @John in fact, I've been doing that since the beginning, it don't give a perfect square signal (AT ALL) but it works. I'll add an image of the result expected ;-)

Comment: "in fact, I've been doing that since the beginning, it don't give a perfect square signal (AT ALL) but it works." 1. What changed between then and now, if it "kind of worked" before? 2 .What happens if you put an adequate delay between setting the pins high and low?

Comment: @John 1) The only change is that I have the "GPIO command" part of the program in a class...      2) Well, I've set a 1s delay between each instruction, it seems to work... So, apparently, the fact of putting all that in a class makes it waaaaaaay slower and I was not really able to get it on the scope... Got a clue why?

Comment: What version raspberry pi are you using? Did you change the pin numbers at all between the working version and this version?

Comment: "I've set a 1s delay between each instruction, it seems to work." can you show this code where you add the 1s delay? I don't quite understand what you mean. This timeline is getting confusing for me and I'm not sure when you're doing each of these trouble shooting steps.

Comment: I wouldn't call this a constraint of classes/objects so much as I'd call this a constraint of the `wiringPi` library and the raspberry pi hardware. There's no reason that this EXACT code (the infinite loop), when placed in a class should operate differently than if it were placed in your `main` function. I have to guess that you're doing something different. Before you put it into the class, there was some delay you were introducing that you're no longer introducing.

Comment: This question is turning into quite a large monster. My suggestion: REWRITE your code that shows the expected behavior, for one single pin, where you toggle the pin in `main`. REWRITE your code that shows the unexpected behavior, for one single pin, where you you toggle the pin in a class. Focus on the MINIMAL part of [example]. I know you just want to code dump, but this question is getting unmaintainable and hard to read, and I can't tell what's going on anymore. I can only guess what your old code that "used to work" looked like. Who knows why it was "correct"?

Comment: @john Well... I've put this while(1) loop back in the main and still have the same result... And the answer bumped in my head while I was writing. THE thing that changed is the "std::cout". This costs 6µs. So, thanks A LOT for your time and your patience. I have things to try now  :-)

Comment: So did you solve it? If you want software contorlled PWM - it looks like the wiringpi library provides that. http://wiringpi.com/reference/software-pwm-library/ you don't need to try to write it from scratch.

Comment: @john Yes, I know that, but the thing is that the GPIO pins of the raspberry pi are really limited in number... I need to control about 16 motors with the capability to recover their speed (through an optocoupler), so I pass through a "shift register" to have enough outputs and I'm creating a digitally controlled PWM generator to control my motors PWMs... so, I'll need 'only' 16x2 outputs and 16 inputs  ^^,

Comment: It sounds like you need to upgrade your hardware. You're using an external chip to control all the outputs? Sounds hairy. It can be done, but good luck.

Comment: It looks like you want to use `delay` to delay for a certain number of milliseconds, not `sleep`. Like in the examples. If you know you need to strobe an output high for a certain amount of time, put in a delay afterwards. Don't rely on unrelated extra cycles in your code to put in a virtual delay for you. http://wiringpi.com/examples/blink/

Comment: @john In fact, I made my own chip with some 74HC595 and I'm controlling it. The code you see here is just for tests purpose, I've been controlling motors successfully, but not with classes and not with PWM. For the PWM, I'll use a DAC and some circuitry to create it. I don't want to use "delay" or "sleep" in fact, after testing, the smaller "delay" time I can have is 1ms (way too long) even with the "chrono". it already worked with just switching ON/OFF without delay ;)